# navigator.getUserMedia() audio recording - howto set volume input level of microphone?

Tags: javascript, html, audio, volume

The `navigator.getUserMedia(....)` call can be used in some modern browser to record audio in Javascript.

Is there a way to adjust/set the input volume level of the microphone?

The setting for this is not always optimal. Sometimes the microphone is set to record only at a very very low input volume. Sure the user could adjust manually the input volume level in his system, but most of my users might lack the knowledge to do this. Therefore it would be best I could adjust the microphone volume dynamically inside of the very JavaScript application which records the data via the "`navigator.getUserMedia(....)`" way?

Are there solutions out there to influence this input volume level of the microphone?

Answer (score 9):

The [Web Audio](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Web_Audio_API) API enables you to change the input of the microphone for the stream.

Here is an example, which shows how to convert a `MediaStream` to another `MediaStream`, but with the ability to change the volume on the fly. If you just want to play back the audio, then you can change `gainNode.connect(dest)` to `gainNode.connect(ctx.destination)` and remove the two other lines that use the `dest` variable.

```js
if (!navigator.getUserMedia) {
    navigator.getUserMedia = navigator.webkitGetUserMedia ||
        navigator.mozGetUserMedia;
}
navigator.getUserMedia({
    audio: true
}, function(stream) {
    var ctx = new AudioContext();
    var source = ctx.createMediaStreamSource(stream);
    var dest = ctx.createMediaStreamDestination();
    var gainNode = ctx.createGain();

    source.connect(gainNode);
    gainNode.connect(dest);
    document.getElementById('volume').onchange = function() {
        gainNode.gain.value = this.value; // Any number between 0 and 1.
    };
    gainNode.gain.value = document.getElementById('volume').value;
    
    // Example: play the audio
    // Or if you use WebRTC, use peerConnection.addStream(dest.stream);
    new Audio(URL.createObjectURL(dest.stream)).play();

    // Store the source and destination in a global variable
    // to avoid losing the audio to garbage collection.
    window.leakMyAudioNodes = [source, dest];
}, function(e) {
    alert(e); // TODO: Handle error.
});

// For the demo only:
document.getElementById('volume').onchange = function() {
    alert('Please provide access to the microhone before using this.');
};
```

```html
Volume: <input type=range id=volume min=0 max=1 value=1 step=0.01>
```

Note: The live demo via Stack snippet does not work in Chrome because getUserMedia seems non-functional for sandboxed frames. If you use Chrome, try snippet at: https://robwu.nl/s/mediasource-change-volume.html

Comment: Reported getUserMedia in sandbox issue as https://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=488882.