# HTML5 audio how to prevent browser microphones pick up all sounds

Tags: javascript, asp.net, vb.net, html, audio

In my sample asp.net/vb.net project for HTML5 audio, using Matt Diamond's recorder.js, when I grant any browser access to my microphone, I can hear every noise around me in the headset speakers (e.g., someone typing next to me, people speaking, etc).  I'm using a Logitech USB headset, but am not sure the specific model as they're provided through work.

Does anyone know if this is a browser-related issue with the microphone (or possibly resulting from the headset I'm using)?  I'm trying to find a different headset to test with, but work typically buys the same model for everyone.

I've tried a few other sites that have demos for recording and play back, and can still hear everything around me once I grant the microphone access (although some demos seem do better at not picking up the background noises).

My knowledge of audio is very limited as I've never worked with audio at the level of normalizing, setting gain, etc.  Any resources or suggestions would be greatly appreciated!

I can include a copy of the aspx and vb.net pages from my sample project if that would be helpful.  Thanks!

Comment: it is nothing about the browser or the code or anything - it is just sound and it is all around you - if you want to record audio you need isolation.

Comment: You can lower microphone level and boost in system audio settings (recording devices). So that only loud or close to mic sounds will be on recording.

Comment: Also look into this question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21574335/navigator-getusermedia-audio-recording-howto-set-volume-input-level-of-micro

Comment: Ceylan, we currently use Nanogong applet which does not pick up background noises under the exact same conditions/scenario. NPAPI has been phased out of all browsers except Firefox (which will happen at the end of this year). Given that Nanogong records fine is why I was wondering if the sound issues with HTML5 audio could be browser-related.  :)

Comment: Andrey, thank you for you suggestions and I will definitely take a look at the link you provided!

Answer (score 1):

Well, the issue turned out to be my fault due to uncommenting a line of Javascript that caused the audio to feedback directly.  Guess that's part of learning something new. :)

Here's the function I used from Matt Diamond's example with the line commented out that I must have incorrectly uncommented at some point...

```
            function startUserMedia(stream) {
            var input = audio_context.createMediaStreamSource(stream);
            console.log('Media stream created.');

            // Uncomment if you want the audio to feedback directly
           // input.connect(audio_context.destination);

            try {
                recorder = new Recorder(input);

            } catch (e) {
                alert('Error: Unable to record. Please check your sound settings, and allow the browser access to your microphone when prompted.');
                console.log('Error: Recorder object could not be created. Msg: ' + e.toString());
            }
        }
```

Thank you for the responses that were provided!  I'm sure I'll have more audio questions to come, lol.