# WebRTC - How to adjust microphone volume on a video stream?

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, web, web-applications, webrtc

I'm trying to adjust the microphone volume in WebRTC chat app which using 2 videos for streaming. 
It is possible to modify the gain of the microphone? If yes, how can I do it to the following streams I'm using?

```
/*********************** video call ***************************/
var localStream;

var localVideo = document.getElementById("localVideo");
var remoteVideo = document.getElementById("remoteVideo");
var callButton = document.getElementById("callButton");

var inputLevelSelector = document.getElementById('mic-volume');
var outputLevelSelector = document.getElementById('speaker-volume');
inputLevelSelector.addEventListener('change', changeMicrophoneLevel);
outputLevelSelector.addEventListener('change', changeSpeakerLevel);

callButton.disabled = true;
callButton.onclick = call;

navigator.getUserMedia = navigator.getUserMedia ||
    navigator.webkitGetUserMedia || navigator.mozGetUserMedia || navigator.msGetUserMedia;
navigator.getUserMedia({
        audio: true,
        video: true
    }, gotStream, //note that we are adding both audio and video
    function (error) {
        console.log(error);
    });

var RTCPeerConnection = window.RTCPeerConnection || window.mozRTCPeerConnection || window.webkitRTCPeerConnection;
var SessionDescription = window.RTCSessionDescription || window.mozRTCSessionDescription || window.webkitRTCSessionDescription;
var pc = new RTCPeerConnection({
    "iceServers": []
});

function gotStream(stream) {
    // localVideo.src = window.URL.createObjectURL(stream); // DEPRECATED
    localVideo.srcObject = stream; // UPDATED
    localStream = stream;
    callButton.disabled = false;
    pc.addStream(stream);
}

pc.onicecandidate = function (event) {
    console.log(event);
    if (!event || !event.candidate) {
        return;
    } else {
        socket.emit("video call", {
            type: "iceCandidate",
            "candidate": event.candidate
        });
    }
};

var remoteStream;
pc.onaddstream = function (event) {
    remoteStream = event.stream;
    var remoteVideo = document.getElementById("remoteVideo");
    // remoteVideo.src = window.URL.createObjectURL(event.stream); // DEPRECATED
    remoteVideo.srcObject = event.stream; // UPDATED
    remoteVideo.play();
};
```

*Please take in note that I'm newbie, so take it easy! :)*

Comment: Does this answer your question? [navigator.getUserMedia() audio recording - howto set volume input level of microphone?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21574335/navigator-getusermedia-audio-recording-howto-set-volume-input-level-of-micro)

Comment: Seems like it. How can I adapt it to WebRTC though? If I just use `peerConnection.addStream(dest.stream);` it's throwing the following error `peerConnection is not defined`

Comment: That is error is thrown because you named your peer connection variable `pc` and not `peerConnection`. Although `peerConnection` would be the better option as everyone would be able to tell what the value is by reading the name of the variable.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here below I've made an implementation of the post that I've shared in the comments. It's the same setup but with your code included.

You first create your nodes from the Web Audio API. Because you want to manipulate the volume of a stream you'll need a [`MediaStreamAudioSourceNode`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/MediaStreamAudioSourceNode), a [`MediaStreamAudioDestinationNode`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/MediaStreamAudioDestinationNode) and a [`GainNode`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/GainNode). The `MediaStreamAudioSourceNode` is entry point for the stream. By injecting it here we can connect it through the gain. The stream will pass through the `GainNode` where the volume will be controlled and then passed to the `MediaStreamAudioDestinationNode` where you can use the stream again in your RTC client.

From there use the stream from you get from the `MediaStreamAudioDestinationNode.stream` property.

### Edit:

It turns out that the `MediaStreamAudioDestinationNode.stream` is a `MediaStream` object with only a audio track. So the video has been removed from the stream and has to be rejoined.

So when you are able to access the stream, get the video tracks from the stream and store them in a variable. Then after passing the stream through the Web Audio API join the video tracks back with the audio tracks that went through the `GainNode`.

```js
var inputLevelSelector = document.getElementById('mic-volume');

// Renamed the variable after your comment.
var peerConnection = new RTCPeerConnection({
    "iceServers": []
});

function gotStream(stream) {

  // Get the videoTracks from the stream.
  const videoTracks = stream.getVideoTracks();

  /**
   * Create a new audio context and build a stream source,
   * stream destination and a gain node. Pass the stream into 
   * the mediaStreamSource so we can use it in the Web Audio API.
   */
  const context = new AudioContext();
  const mediaStreamSource = context.createMediaStreamSource(stream);
  const mediaStreamDestination = context.createMediaStreamDestination();
  const gainNode = context.createGain();

  /**
   * Connect the stream to the gainNode so that all audio
   * passes through the gain and can be controlled by it.
   * Then pass the stream from the gain to the mediaStreamDestination
   * which can pass it back to the RTC client.
   */
  mediaStreamSource.connect(gainNode);
  gainNode.connect(mediaStreamDestination);

  /**
   * Change the gain levels on the input selector.
   */
  inputLevelSelector.addEventListener('input', event => {
    gainNode.gain.value = event.target.value;
  });

  /**
   * The mediaStreamDestination.stream outputs a MediaStream object
   * containing a single AudioMediaStreamTrack. Add the video track
   * to the new stream to rejoin the video with the controlled audio.
   */
  const controlledStream = mediaStreamDestination.stream;
  for (const videoTrack of videoTracks) {
    controlledStream.addTrack(videoTrack);
  }

  /**
   * Use the stream that went through the gainNode. This
   * is the same stream but with altered input volume levels.
   */
  localVideo.srcObject = controlledStream;
  localStream = controlledStream;
  peerConnection.addStream(controlledStream);
  callButton.disabled = false;

}
```

Comment: Thank for your time, really appreciated! Although just the audio showing up, I want to have both audio and video.

Comment: Try changing the `localVideo.srcObject` stream back to the original `stream` value, like it was before. Changing the stream probably messes up the video. `localVideo.srcObject = stream`.

Comment: The localStream is ok now (video) but the remoteStream is just audio instead of video too.

Comment: I've looked into it. It seems that when you pass the stream through the Web Audio API, only the audio tracks are returned. So you'll need to get the video tracks first and add them to the audio tracks to recreate the stream. So in other words: the video and audio get split and need to be rejoined to form a single stream with both audio and video. Try it out. I'm curious if it solves your issue.

Comment: I was thinking the same thing. Seems like I have to remove the audio from the stream and add the gained one, although I have no clue how I can do that :/

Comment: I've edities the answer where I've added the video tracks to the audio.

Comment: OMG, it's working. Thank you so much for your time Emiel! Really, really appreciated it! I was searching for a week to make it work. Thank you again!

Comment: You're welcome, this has been educational for myself as well. Have a good one!